# Apache POI – Excel (poi-bin-3.17) not working on Selenium Get WARNING Error?

Tags: apache-poi

Retrieve data from an excel sheet,using Following code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    public class poi_excel {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream("F:\\Selenium Using Web Driver\\Plugins\\HEC_login.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheet("script");
        XSSFRow row=sheet.getRow(1);
        XSSFCell cell=row.getCell(1);
        String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println(value);
                }    }
```

following error occur

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$1 (file:/F:/Selenium%20Using%20Web%20Driver/Plugins/poi-bin-3.17-20170915/poi-3.17/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar) to field java.io.FilterInputStream.in
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at poi_excel.main(poi_excel.java:16)
```

Kindly provide solution to resolve this problem.

Comment: About the warnings: [Can Apache POI be compiled/used with Java 9?](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N102B0). And about the NPE: [XSSFSheet.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getRow-int-) as well as [XSSFRow.getCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.html#getCell-int-) may return `null`. So as always with NPE, you have to check if the object is  `null` before using the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
XSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheet("script.type");
```

Enter the file type (.xlsx or whatever) in place of `type` and try again.

**Edit:** Also check whether the file is in the working directory.